# Bootstrap slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the bootstrap tabnavigation as a slideshow like switching the tabs automatically and I want to reset the timer when user click the navigation buttons, but here  it is not working please help me to fix the problem in this script.
 I tried it here **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/5K85d/1/)**

```
tabSlideshowSetup('#slideshowOne');
tabSlideshowSetup('#slideshowTwo');

function tabSlideshowSetup(parent) {
    var toime = 0;
    var tabs = $(parent).children('.dot-nav > li');
    var tabsPagenationDots = $(parent).children('.dot-nav > li > a');
    function imgFunc(){
      var  active = tabs.filter('.active'),
        next = active.next('li'),
        toClick = next.length ? next.find('a') : tabs.eq(0).find('a');
        toClick.trigger('click');
        clearInterval(toime);
        toime=setInterval(imgFunc, 18000);
    }
    toime=setInterval(imgFunc, 18000);
    tabsPagenationDots.click(function(){
        clearInterval(toime);
        toime=setInterval(imgFunc, 18000);
    });
}
```

Html code is here:,

```
<div id="slideshowOne" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="tab-content row-fluid" id="testimonial-section"> 
            <div class="row-fluid tab-pane active" id="ttta">
                    <p class="testimonial-detail"><a href="https://twitter.com/anandlunia" target="_blank">Anand Lunia</a>, <small> India Quotient Founder, Angel Investor </small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid tab-pane" id="tttb">
                    <p class="testimonial-detail"><a href="https://twitter.com/Raghu_Dixit" target="_blank">Raghu Dixit</a>, <small>Renowned Musician </small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid tab-pane" id="tttc">
                    <p class="testimonial-detail"><a href="https://twitter.com/surekhapillai" target="_blank">Surekha Pillai</a>, <small>Communications Consultant </small></p>
            </div>
          </div>  
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs dot-nav" id="testimonial_tab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

<div id="slideshowTwo" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="tab-content row-fluid" id="testimonial-section"> 
            <div class="row-fluid tab-pane active" id="ttta">
                    <p class="testimonial-detail"><a href="https://twitter.com/anandlunia" target="_blank">Anand Lunia</a>, <small> India Quotient Founder, Angel Investor </small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid tab-pane" id="tttb">
                    <p class="testimonial-detail"><a href="https://twitter.com/Raghu_Dixit" target="_blank">Raghu Dixit</a>, <small>Renowned Musician </small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid tab-pane" id="tttc">
                    <p class="testimonial-detail"><a href="https://twitter.com/surekhapillai" target="_blank">Surekha Pillai</a>, <small>Communications Consultant </small></p>
            </div>
          </div>  
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs dot-nav" id="testimonial_tab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just some tips. **HTML:** You're overusing the `row-fluid` class. It's unnecessary **JS:** You're misusing the `children()` function. Use `find` instead.

Comment: @Itay Hi I did the changes what you are saying then also its not working see here http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/5K85d/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/5K85d/7/)

```
tabsPagenationDots.click(function () {
        clearInterval(toime);
        toime = setInterval(imgFunc, 3000);
        tabsBox.hide();

        var index = tabsPagenationDots.index(this);

        tabsBox.eq(index).show();
    });
```

Comment: @ltay Hi what you have done is good :). I upvoted your answer also, But here the problem is I cant add this [data-panel] attribute in each tabs because I have some 15 tabs in my website so please tell me some another way to fix this. Thanks,

Comment: @ltay Hi you are awesome thank you so much for this :) And I accepted your answer also. :)